# Most Efficient Way to Populate UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uinavigationcontroller, plist

I am developing an app which consists of a `UINavigationController` and `UITableViews`, there will be many items (50+) at the root view of the nav controller and maybe 30 rows in each of the detail views.

What is the most efficient way to populate the lists? Core Data or Plists?

There is scope within the specification to push updates to the lists on a monthly basis, so they always stay current. Would this affect the choice, which method is easier to bulk update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would choose Core Data.

It is relatively easy to use; and it gives you more flexibility if the app needs to grow. Core Data can be backed by SQLLite, and thus can be quite performant. Also bulk updates is manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is by far the best, especially since you want to be able to make updates to this data later on

Regarding updates. I wouldn't 'push' these out but rather have the app poll for them, perhaps on launch, then fetch anything new in the background.

Edit: Also with Core Data and using a NSFetchedResultsController it is very easy to smoothly animate in new records into a UITableView as they are added in the background to the data store

Answer (score 0):

Imho, I would try to keep things simple, following the good old [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.

In your current case, it seems that you just need to display read-only data, so all you need is the data (say a file, in plist format, or xml, or json, or csv, or whatever. just parse the file, populate your business objects, add them to an array. Use that array for your master and detail view. No need for core data here (asumming by 50+ you don't mean 50 - 50'000, because in that case, core data's memory management would help ;-)

If in the future you need to handle updates, you will either update the whole list, thus in fact just replace the old file (simple), or do incremental changes. I would only recommend to consider to start using core data in the latter case.

I'm personally using core data in a couple of projects, and I love it. But I wouldn't recommend it just because it's there, after all it brings overhead and complexity. If you want to use core data, you'll need to invest some time to understand it's concepts. Don't underestimate that, there's a lot of stuff to read and understand, and probably a couple of WTF moments (just look for core data questions here in SO).

Just to be clear: I don't want to talk you out of using core data, I'm just asking as your mother probably would: do you really need it?